# Can't load fixtures in other environment

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

In my `composer.json`, I added `doctrine-fixtures-bundle` in `require-dev` as recommended in the documentation

```
"require-dev": {
    "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "^3.3",
    ...
},
```

I created a new symfony `benchmark` environment, but I cannot access the fixtures :

```
$ APP_ENV=benchmark php bin/console doctrine:fixtures:load
```

> You may be looking for a command provided by the "DoctrineFixturesBundle" which is currently not installed. Try running "composer require doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle --dev"

Fixtures is available in dev. **How to make it also accessible in benchmark environment ?**

*I don't think adding fixtures in `require` to `composer.json` is a good idea : it's not safe.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not define this library as a `dev` dependency then. Move it from the `require-dev` to the `require` section and reinstall vendors with Composer.

It's "not safe" as in you could potentially load the fixtures on production and erase your database. If you are afraid you could do so, you can load this bundle for the `benchmark` environment only, eg.:

```
// config/bundles.php
Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\DoctrineFixturesBundle::class => ['dev' => true, 'benchmark' => true],
```